# Select data from 2 tables (Simple)

Tags: sql

I retreived a number `CID` and a number `ACN` from a relational table `RELCIF`

But now I also want to see the string `CLS` from `ACN`

I did this and only shows the first select:

```
select CID,ACN from RELCIF
select CLS from ACN
```

How can I see all the data in one table?

Comment: can you share the table schema?  if the tables have any columns which are associate then you use Inner join .

Comment: You want to use a `JOIN`.  It will be something like `SELECT R.CID, R.ACN, A.CLS FROM RELCIF R JOIN ACN A ON R.ACN = A.ACN` where the `ON` join predicate should be whichever field links the two tables together.  I took a guess at that part.

Comment: I cant. But CID and ACN show well. But I wanted to also fetch the data of CLS from that ACN number.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select CID, ACN, '' as CLS from RELCIF
UNION
SELECT '' as CID, '' as ACN, CLs from ACN
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to "Join" the two tables together in your `FROM` clause. I'm guessing at your column names here, but it would look something like:

```
SELECT RELCIF.CID, RELCIF.ACN, ACN.CLS 
FROM RELCIF 
    INNER JOIN ACN 
        ON RELCIF.ACN = ACN.ACN;
```

Here we "INNER JOIN" the two tables. We tell it on the `ON` clause how the two tables are related.

This SQL statement says: "Join the two tables using the field `ACN` from `RELCIF` table where it is equal to the `ACN` field from the `ACN` table. Then output the `CID` and `ACN` fields from `RELCIF` table and the `CLS` field from the `ACN` table."

Comment: @Tiago Great to hear!